# Reading file from s3 in pyspark using org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Trying to read files from s3 using hadoop-aws, The command used to run code is mentioned below.
please help me resolve this and understand what I am doing wrong.

```
# run using command
# time spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.1 connect_s3_using_keys.py

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import ConfigParser
import pyspark

# create Spark context with Spark configuration
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Deepak_1ST_job")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

hadoop_conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("/home/deepak/Desktop/secure/awsCred.cnf")
accessKeyId = config.get("aws_keys", "access_key")
secretAccessKey = config.get("aws_keys", "secret_key")

hadoop_conf.set(
    "fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs3a.access.key", accessKeyId)
hadoop_conf.set("s3a.secret.key", secretAccessKey)

sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://bucket_name/logs/20191117log.json")
df.show()
```

EDIT 1:

As I am new to pyspark I am unaware of these dependencies, also the error is not easily understandable.

getting error as

```
File "/home/deepak/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 98, in deco
  File "/home/deepak/spark/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.json.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:816)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.lookupPassword(S3AUtils.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.getAWSAccessKeys(S3AUtils.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider.
```

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing ? What have you tried till now to resolve it ? Do add all those details for someone to help you better.

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman I have added the error please check.
I am new to pyspark

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue with spark 3.0.0 / hadoop 3.2.

What worked for me was to replace the `hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar` in `spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2/jars` with `hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar` found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0

Comment: Im using a linux machine, i dont already have the hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar or any version of hadoop-aws jar. How do i get this jar, and set it up?

Comment: Is just just wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar and move the file to jars folder or is there something more that i should do?

Answer (score 1):

Check your spark guava jar version. If you download spark from Amazon like me from the link (https://aws-glue-etl-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/glue-3.0/spark-3.1.1-amzn-0-bin-3.2.1-amzn-3.tgz) in their documentation. You can see the include guava version is guava-14.0.1.jar and their container is using guava-21.0.jar

I have reported the issue to them and they will repack their spark to include the correct version. If you interested in the bug self, here is the link. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#ClassNotFoundException:_org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem