# fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop

I'm trying to read data from S3 using spark using following dependencies and configurations:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.2.1"
```

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", config.s3AccessKey)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", config.s3SecretKey)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
```

I'm getting error as
**java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider not found**

It was working fine with older version of spark and hadoop. To be exact, i was previously using spark version 2.4.8 and hadoop version 2.8.5

Comment: The  class you asked for is still there; as should be the one which isn't. there's hints of classpath issues here.

Comment: You should look at the artifact and JARs really used at runtime and/or run a dependency tree command with SBT to see if there are some evicted dependencies because of conflicts

Comment: There is no class named **IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider** in org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth in hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar. Am I missing something here? @stevel

Comment: emr is its own fork of hadoop; you shoulld be using the s3a connector there. probably the cause of problems

Comment: Hi were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking forward to use the latest EMR version with spark 3.2.0 and hadoop 3.2.1. This issue basically was faced mainly because of [hadoop 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123122/reading-file-from-s3-in-pyspark-using-org-apache-hadoophadoop-aws) and hence the only option was to use older version of EMR. Spark 2.4.8 and hadoop 2.10.1 worked for me.